# Spring Data REST unable to instantiate PagedResourcesAssembler

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I' m trying to expose a custom controller method that should return a PagedResources response using the PagedResourcesAssembler, but I end up with following error when invoking the controller method:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.data.web.PagedResourcesAssembler.<init>()
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:102) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
```

**Controller**

```
@RepositoryRestController
public class XDetailController {
@Autowired
private final XDetailRepositoryImpl xDetailRepo;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/affiliates/{id}/xdetails") 
public @ResponseBody PagedResources<Resource<XDetail>> getAffiliateXDetails(@PathVariable Integer id, Pageable page, PagedResourcesAssembler<XDetail> assembler) {

    Page<XDetail> xDetails = xDetailRepo.findByPersonId(id, page);      
    PagedResources<Resource<XDetail>> resources = assembler.toResource(xDetails, linkTo(methodOn(XDetailController.class).getAffiliateXDetails(id, page, assembler)).withSelfRel());
    for(Resource<XDetail> resource : resources){
        resource.add(linkTo(methodOn(XDetailController.class).getXDetail(resource.getContent().getId())).withSelfRel());
    }                   
    return resources;
}
```

I have no special config in my Application class, which is annotated with @SpringBootApplication

Missing some configuration or Spring bug?

**UPDATE**

It works with @RestController annotation on my controller instead of @RepositoryRestController. But still, I would expect it should work for @RepositoryRestController